# .NET C# - Both Bitmap and Image Loads Images Smaller than Expected

Tags: c#, .net, image, bitmap, load

I'm trying to process the typical 16 megapixel images from a modern camera.  Picking a random image, both the file system and my image editing software says the image is 4608 x 3456.  When I load the image in C# (VS2013 .Net 4.5) using either new Bitmap(filename) or Image.FromFile(filename), I get an image successfully loaded.  However, the resulting image has a size of 1613 x 1210.  Now, in some cases I want to create custom size thumbnails, and this will work ok.  However, I have another need where I detect "non normal" orientations and I simply want to flip/rotate for display, then save.

Saving these images (without any adjustments, just load and save) creates a valid image on disk.  However, both the file system AND my image tool says the size is 1613 x 1210.

How do I load the full size image and preserve all info back to disk?  Any ideas as to what I'm doing wrong?  I just want to rotate the image where needed, I don't want to shrink it!

Here's a snippet of what I tried, as promised in a comment below:

```
Bitmap bm = new Bitmap(fileName);
Image jpg = Image.FromFile(fileName);
jpg.Save("e:\\test.jpg");
bm.Save("e:\\test2.jpg");
```

Both files are smaller than their original size, and match the width and height the debugger shows for both in-memory images.

Per a suggested answer, I tried this code but saw no difference in the results:

```
long width = 0;
long height = 0;

byte[] imageBytes = File.ReadAllBytes(fileName);
using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(imageBytes))
{
    Image jpg3 = Image.FromStream(ms);
    width = jpg3.Width;
    height = jpg3.Height;
    jpg3.Save("e:\\test3.jpg",System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
}
```

Thanks in advance.

[EDIT] 
User Error from a followup post:

> While it's true I do have a 4608x3456 size image of the very picture I
>   am trying to load, I selected the wrong directory in my OpenFileDialog
>   and was actually selected a, you guessed it, 1613 x 1210 version of
>   this image. *The code WAS loading the full thing, the silly operator
>   (me) was gumming it up.*
>
> Before I post, I'll try the full-size image ... yeah, it works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you show your program code?
I downloaded 5169x3423 size sample image.
Load this image using program and when i restored it, original and new image are same.

I load image file to byte array and save it to Bitmap.

```
private Image LoadImage()
{
    OpenFileDialog openFile = new OpenFileDialog();
    openFile.ShowDialog();
    byte[] byteImage = File.ReadAllBytes(openFile.FileName);

    Image myImage;
    using (var ms = new MemoryStream(byteImage))
    {
        myImage = Image.FromStream(ms);
    }
    return myImage;
 }


private void SaveImage(Image myImage)
{
    Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(myImage);        
    // Temp save location
    bmp.Save("c:\\test\\myImage.jpg", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
}
```

Comment: I'll provide a snippet, but the calls are not very complicated.  I DID try Image.FromStream at one point but I did NOT load the stream the same way you did.  I will try it.  However, here's what I did (reconstruction, since I've tries so many other things!  Er, no formatting here.  I'll just add this to my original question.  Thanks for the reply.

Comment: Ok, I tried loading into a MemoryStream first and was able to create and then save an image from that.  Unfortunately, the size while debugging still matches the resulting image size on disk, which is the same size that I was getting with the direct method calls in my snippet.